# Reality Composer – Is it possible to assign vertical and horizontal anchors simultaneously?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, realitykit, reality-composer

I’ve been learning about RealityKit lately, and have come across Reality Composer. However, it seems that in the app the user can only have one anchor at a time.

I was wondering if it is at all possible to have two anchors in a scene, a vertical and a horizontal. I’m trying to detect a floor and walls that can interact with physics bodies and need both for the game to properly function.

I don’t need to know the positions or anything about the vertical anchors, I just need them to have physics bodies.

Does Reality Composer allow for more than one anchor in a scene? I know that RealityKit allows for this, but I don’t know if scenes created in Reality Composer can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reality Composer v1.5 can't allow you to simultaneously use two different types of Anchors at the moment**. Here are five types of Anchors you can use in RC (and only one anchor per one scene):

- **Horizontal** (à la ARPlaneAnchor)
- **Vertical** (à la ARPlaneAnchor)
- **Image** (à la ARImageAnchor)
- **Face** (à la ARFaceAnchor)
- **Object** (à la ARObjectAnchor)

**But you can use two different types of Anchors at a time in RealityKit**.

In RealityKit there are three types of alignment:

```
AnchoringComponent.Target.Alignment.horizontal
AnchoringComponent.Target.Alignment.vertical

/* Entity can be anchored to surfaces of Any alignment */
AnchoringComponent.Target.Alignment.any
```

> An `Alignment` struct conforms to `OptionSet` protocol, so you can use 2 types simultaneously:

```
let anchor = AnchorEntity(plane: [.horizontal, .vertical],
                  minimumBounds: [0.2, 0.2])
```

or you can setup it through `AnchoringComponent`:

```
anchor.anchoring = AnchoringComponent(.plane(.any, 
                             classification: .any, 
                              minimumBounds: [0.1, 0.1]))
```

or you can use `reanchor()` instance method:

```
let houseScene = try! Experience.loadHouseScene()

houseScene.reanchor(.plane(.any, classification: .any, 
                                  minimumBounds: [0.1, 0.1]), 
                       preservingWorldTransform: false)
```

You can read [this story](https://medium.com/@arkit/realitykit-911-how-to-enable-both-vertical-and-horizontal-plane-detection-20718d409275) to find out how it looks like in real code.